# How to trigger certain segue for a selected nib cell in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, xib

I have 2 custom nib cells in my table view that should perform 2 different segues. I want something like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // if nib cell A is selected
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("aSegue", sender: self)
    // if nib cell B is selected
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("aDifferentSegue", sender: self)
}
```

My nib cells have identifiers but that property doesn't seem accessible in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. The nib cells are randomly displayed inside my table view, not ordered.

e.g.

- nib cell A
- nib cell B
- nib cell A
- nib cell A
- nib cell B

Not

- nib cell A
- nib cell A
- nib cell A
- nib cell B
- nib cell B

What is the best way to access something unique within the table view cell to perform a conditional segue?

Comment: Need more information on how you are creating these cells. The usual way of determining what cell has been tapped is to use the index path. You cells' contents are being populated from an array of of "something" right? The alternative is to get the cell inside your didSelectRow with cellForRow and check the title/description/ whatever and switch on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you say something like

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) is NibAClass
        {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("aSegue", sender: self)
        }
        if self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) is NibBClass
        {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("aDifferentSegue", sender: self)
        }
}
```